# Is it possible to direct mount an EXT4 disk with data on it to a XenServer guest vm?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, xenserver

I have a few ext4 disks (3GB each) with data on them (almost full).  And I would like to mount them on a Xenserver, and have them mounted directly to an Ubuntu guest vm.  Is this possible? (and easy.  I am a newbie with Xenserver).  I am trying to convert a fileserver to a xenserver but still serve files (ie: one of the vm will be a fileserver).  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I too have looked into this. I believe it is possible although I'm more curious about the stability of it.

Some reading/instructions:http://techblog.conglomer.net/sata-direct-local-disk-access-on-xenserver/

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/add-hard-drive-citrix-xenserver

Might want to look at second link first as it explains how to add the hard drive to the host first, then the first link explains how to attach to a VM.

I haven't tried this yet. Am in the process of switching my file server around to create a viable XenServer so I can practice with spare hdds. Since you are a newbie with Xenserver like myself, I suggest you do the same :)

Hope this helps you, if not points you in the right direction. Let me know how you get on anyway.

Regards
Jono

Comment: Thanks Jono! I have read link #2 before and actually have done adding drive successfully.  But link #1 is good, adding as removable drive, interesting, never will thought of that.  Agree with you also regarding stability.  I guess time will tell ;-)  Thanks again!!!